# Что означает звездочка и единица?

Tags: php

```
    // Фильтруем полученные данные
$del = $_GET['del'] * 1;
```

Это часть кода и учебного курса(гостевая книга) , обьясните пожалуйста, что означает звездочка и единица?

```
   Спасибо!
```

Comment: означает она бред. :)

т.к. ни к селу, ни к городу.

Comment: Согласен, что бред, но по сути эффект будет такой же, как от использования функции **intval()**.

Answer (score 1):

Равнозначно `(int)$_GET['del']`

Comment: Не равнозначно.

Comment: Поясните!?

Comment: Например так:
    
    $str = '15.5';
    echo $str * 1; // 15.5
    echo (int)$str; // 15

Comment: согласен, Вы правы

Comment: но для гостевой книги (int) наверняка нужно для удаления ийдишников с базы, так что лучше использовать (int) нежели floatval().

Comment: @ROOT, можно только догадываться, что прилетает в переменной **$_GET['del']** (ТС не удосужился поставить в известность). Понятное дело, что если там ID записи в таблице, то нужно целочисленное значение.

Answer (score 0):

```
$_GET['del'] * 1
```

Это не правильная фильтрация! И это эквивалент — `+$_GET['del']`